# How to implement an auto scroll view like notification center's stock ticker?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiscrollview, core-animation

I want to implement a scroll view which looks like the stock ticker. It can respond slide or tap gesture.

How can I implement this? Please advise me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually I'd setup an container `UIScrollView` with the contents of the scrolling area as subviews. To simulate a circular scroll I'd keep an array of the subviews. I'd add a view just off screen at the starting edge, and take away a view just off screen at ending edge.

`UIScrollViewDelegate` methods will be called when a person starts or stops dragging the view, which you can use to start and stop the animated scrolling. Other methods in this protocol can be used to reset the contents of the scrollview when the edge is reached, so more views can be added as needed.

I'd probably use a `CADisplayLink` to manually manage the animations. The method given to the `CADisplayLink` would update the scroll and manage adding and subtracting views to the edges. It would also stop scrolling based on a flag set by the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods when the person is dragging the scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `NSTimer` to reposition the `contentOffset` of your Scrollview.
Use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` to stop your animation while the user is dragging the scrollview.

Answer (score -2):

Unless you jailbreak, you can't put custom views in Notification Centre.

Comment: I don't want to put custom views into Notification center, I just want to implement an auto animation scroll view like stock ticker~ Sorry, I'll modify my question.